# regex string which will capture a namespace and replace as required

Tags: regex, kubernetes, fluentd

In my kubernetes cluster we have many namespace and we want to create a ES Index as per namespace, so currently we are adding namespace manually. like below team1(namespace) &  team2(namespace) , So is it possible to use regex which can create a namespace index using regex input

```
input-kubernetes.conf: |
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.team1.*  # namespace
        Path              /var/log/containers/*team1*.log  # namespace
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube_team1.db   # namespace
        Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   Off
        Refresh_Interval  10
        
    [INPUT]
        Name              tail
        Tag               kube.team2.*   # namespace
        Path              /var/log/containers/*team2*.log  # namespace
        Parser            docker
        DB                /var/log/flb_kube_team2.db   # namespace
        Mem_Buf_Limit     5MB
        Skip_Long_Lines   Off
        Refresh_Interval  10
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is it necessary to show both "input" and "output" (both of which are presumeably input)? If not, one is enough to show the problem - please delete the other. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks for advice, edited as required.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. You have  show the input. Can you show the desired output?